# Log Every Value Stored for a Contact in iOS6

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios6

I'm having a really strange problem where I am trying to find a contact's address in iOS 6, and unless the contact has an address labelled "Address", I can't find it. Any addresses entered under "Work" or "Home" just don't appear.

In order to try to figure out this problem, is it possible to take a person record from contacts and just dump every value stored? I'm hoping this will help me find where those "Home" and "Work" addresses are living.

Here's my code so far:

```
- (void)setAddressFromPerson:(ABRecordRef)person
{
    ABMultiValueRef addresses = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonAddressProperty);
    for (CFIndex j = 0; j<ABMultiValueGetCount(addresses);j++){
        CFDictionaryRef dict = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(addresses, j);
        CFStringRef typeTmp = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(addresses, j);
        CFStringRef labeltype = ABAddressBookCopyLocalizedLabel(typeTmp);
        NSString *street = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStreetKey) copy];
        NSString *city = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCityKey) copy];
        NSString *state = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressStateKey) copy];
        NSString *zip = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressZIPKey) copy];
        NSString *country = [(NSString *)CFDictionaryGetValue(dict, kABPersonAddressCountryKey) copy];

        NSLog(street);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit difficult to parse visually, but the easiest way to dump everything associated with an `ABPersonRef` is to get its vCard representation:

```
ABPersonRef person = ...;
CFDataRef data = ABPersonCreateVCardRepresentationWithPeople(@[person]);
NSString *vcard = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

(assume proper casting from `NSArray *` ⇒ `CFArrayRef`, etc)

Comment: Thanks Dave! Turns out the address wasn't stored in the primary contact, and the reason it wasn't showing up was because the address was stored in another contact of the same name. Unified info was on and I didn't realize it.